# How to access files in server for XBAP application which is running in a client machine?

Tags: c#, wpf, webservice-client, xbap

I have an XBAP application deployed in server and running in a client machine. I want to access a set of files from the server to be used in client machine. How can I achieve it?. Should I go for a web service call?

Answer (score 0):

See: [WPF XAML Browser Applications Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) at MSDN.

You can use the siteoforigin